# How to enhance my use of Google Scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

I would like to enhance my use of Google Scholar. Specifically, I am looking for functionalities I do not know whether they exist.

- Is it possible to "follow" a specific paper? I would like Google Scholar to notice every time some other works quote this paper, as I consider they relate strongly to my Ph.D. dissertation.
- Is it possible to get noticed every time specific journals publish papers that include defined keywords in their title or abstract?

I am curious about all the enhanced uses you can have of Google Scholar. If they are extra options, which notably help watching new publication on specific topics, I would be pleased to know them.

Comment: You should check YouTube. There are many great videos on how one can better use Google Scholar.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot follow specific papers or journal-level keywords on Google Scholar; you can only follow researcher profiles.

However, there are other databases that support such a functionality.

### Alert for specific keyword-searches in journals

For instance, on **Web of Science**, you can set an e-mail alert for your search keywords. Using their *Advanced Search* Options, you can design your keywords such that you only search in specific journals and only in their Abstracts and Titles. After you have done your search, click on *Create an alert* in the left menu.

[image: Web of Science screenshot showing how to create an alert for a search]

The same applies to **Scopus** where the option is named *Set alert*:

[image: Scopus screenshot showing how to create an alert for a search]

### Alert for specific papers

On **Web of Science**, click on a search result or publication. On the right-hand side, under the heading 'Citation Network' you can click on *Create Citation Alert*:

[image: Web of Science screenshot for citation alerts]

In **Scopus**, the same function can be found as *Set citation alert*.

[image: Scopus screenshot for citation alerts]

Or on **ResearchGate**, you can get alerts for citations to specific papers by clicking *Follow*:

[image]